# Python Pandas How to save output to csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

Hello now im working on my project. I want to get candidate of text block by using algorithm below.

My input is a csv document which contain :

1. HTML column : the html code in a line
2. TAG column : the tag of html code in a line
3. Words : the text inside the tag in aline
4. TC : the number of words in a line
5. LTC : the number of anchor words in a line
6. TG : the number of tag in a line
7. P : the number of tag p and br in a line
8. CTTD : TC + (0.2*LTC) + TG - P
9. CTTDs : the smoothed CTTD

[image]

This is my algorithm to find candidate of text block. I make the csv file into dataframe using pandas. I am using CTTDs,TC and TG column to find the candidate.

```
from ListSmoothing import get_filepaths_smoothing
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

filenames = get_filepaths_smoothing(r"C:\Users\kimhyesung\PycharmProjects\newsextraction\smoothing")
index = 0
for f in filenames:
    file_html=open(str(f),"r")
    df = pd.read_csv(file_html)
#df = pd.read_csv('smoothing/Smoothing001.csv')

    news = np.array(df['CTTDs'])
    new = np.array(df['TG'])

    minval = np.min(news[np.nonzero(news)])
    maxval = np.max(news[np.nonzero(news)])

    j = 0.2
    thetaCTTD = minval + j * (maxval-minval)
#maxGap = np.max(new[np.nonzero(new)])
#minGap = np.min(new[np.nonzero(new)])
    thetaGap = np.min(new[np.nonzero(new)])
    #print thetaCTTD
    #print maxval
    #print minval
    #print thetaGap
    def create_candidates(df, thetaCTTD, thetaGAP):
        k = 0
        TB = {}
        TC = 0
        for index in range(0, len(df) - 1):
            start = index
            if df.ix[index]['CTTDs'] > thetaCTTD:
                start = index
                gap = 0
                TC = df.ix[index]['TC']
                for index in range(index + 1, len(df) - 1):
                    if df.ix[index]['TG'] == 0:
                        continue
                    elif df.ix[index]['CTTDs'] <= thetaCTTD and gap >= thetaGAP:
                        break
                    elif df.ix[index]['CTTDs'] <= thetaCTTD:
                        gap += 1
                    TC += df.ix[index]['TC']
            if (TC < 1) or (start == index):
                continue
            TB.update({
                k: {
                    'start': start,
                    'end': index - 1
                }
            })
            k += 1
        return TB

    def get_unique_candidate(TB):
        TB = tb.copy()
        for key, value in tb.iteritems():
            if key == len(tb) - 1:
                break
            if value['end'] == tb[key+1]['end']:
                del TB[key+1]
            elif value['start'] < tb[key+1]['start'] < value['end']:
                TB[key]['end'] = tb[key+1]['start'] - 1
            else:
                continue
        return TB

    index += 1
    stored_file = "textcandidate/textcandidate" + '{0:03}'.format(index) + ".csv"
    tb = create_candidates(df, thetaCTTD, thetaGap)
    TB = get_unique_candidate(tb)
    filewrite = open(stored_file, "wb")
    df_list = []
    for (k, d) in TB.iteritems():
        candidate_df = df.loc[d['start']:d['end']]
        candidate_df['candidate'] = k
        df_list.append(candidate_df)
    output_df = pd.concat(df_list)
    output_df.to_csv(stored_file)

    writer = csv.writer(filewrite, lineterminator='\n')
    filewrite.close
```

ThetaCTTD is 10.36 and thethaGap is 1.

The output is

[image]

The output means there are 2 candidates of text block . First the candiate of text block start from line number 215 and end line number 225 (like the pict bellow). And the other candidate of text block start from line number 500 and end line number 501.

My question is how to save the output into csv and not only the number of line but the range of the text block and the others column will appear as the output too?

My expected output is like the screenshot of candidate text block is like this one

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your output is a list of dictionaries:

```
pd.concat([df.loc[d['start']:d['end']] for (k, d) in TB.iteritems()])
```

Note that we slice by label, so `d['end']` will be included.

---

**Edit**: add the candidate number in a new column.

It's cleaner to write a loop than to do two concat operations:

```
df_list = []
for (k, d) in TB.iteritems():
    candidate_df = df.loc[d['start']:d['end']]
    candidate_df['candidate'] = k
    df_list.append(candidate_df)

output_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

It's also faster to concatenate all dataframes at once at the end.

Comment: im sorry i dont get what do you mean. Can you explain to me? what syntax i have to add in my code. i directly add your code in my program but it does not work

Comment: What is the variable that you printed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzlDy.jpg)?

Comment: i print for x in TB.iteritems() : print x . and the output will be The TB.UPDATE

Comment: im sorry your answer did not give me the expected output, when i write your code the output just repeat my latest output, which is (7, {'start': 500, 'end': 501})

Comment: I highly doubt that. The line of code in my answer returns a dataframe, not a tuple. Can you double-check what you are running? Don't forget to print the whole thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133544/discussion-between-kim-hyesung-and-ians).

Comment: im sorry but i need your help. How to save the candidate in a csv but different column? Thank You.

Comment: @KimHyesung I have edited my answer. I believe I deserve an upvote now :)

Comment: ofcourse :) Thank You so much i will upvote another answer

Comment: i know im such a burden because i need your help again :". i tried to use more than one data but why im getting error. could you please check my code? i edited the code above.

Comment: You shouldn't have upvoted all these other answers! Never mind, I'm pretty sure it will be reversed as they have scripts looking for serial up/downvoting.

Comment: I [moved this discussion to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133544/discussion-between-kim-hyesung-and-ians).